One technicality in proving partition and integral gives same definition of arclength
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\alpha:[0,1]\to M$ a smooth curve on $M$. As noted in this post, there are two ways to define the arclength of $\alpha$ (by integration and by partition). I was trying to follow the answers to this post to show that these two definitions are equivalent. In particular I was following the argument of this answer to prove $|\alpha|\geq L(\alpha)$. But there is a claim in this answer that I could not prove:

At any point $\alpha(s_0)$ on the curve, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|s_1-s_0|<\delta$ implies $$\int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|dt\leq (1+\epsilon)d(\alpha(s_0),\alpha(s_1)).$$
And there is a hint by the author: "I just meant that the curve  and the local geodesic at $x_0=\alpha(s_0)$ in the direction of $\alpha'(s_0)$ are both smooth with the same tangent vector at $x_0$ so that the distance of these curves is a $o(|s_0-s_1|)$. And then you get the inequality by the continuity of the metric tensor. "

However, I could not prove this claim, nor do I understand the hint completely. I would appreciate it if anyone could show me how to prove it.
Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt:
I can show that
(*) For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|s_1-s_0|<\delta$ implies $|d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))-|\alpha'(t)|(s_1-s_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $t\in [s_0,s_1]$.
But I have no idea how (*) will imply the desired claim.
Proof of (*): By taking $\delta$ sufficiently small, we may assume that we are in a normal neighborhood of $\alpha(s_0)$. Let $\gamma(t)=\exp_{\alpha(s_0)}(t\alpha'(s_0))$ be the unique geodesic starting at $\alpha(s_0)$ and has initial tangent vector $\alpha'(s_0)$. That is, $\gamma(t)$ is tangent to $\alpha(t)$ at $t=s_0$. Then using the reverse triangle inequality, we have
$$
|d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))-d(\gamma(s_1),\gamma(s_0))|\leq d(\gamma(s_1),\alpha(s_0)).
$$
Note that $\gamma(s_0)=\alpha(s_0)$, and $d(\gamma(s_1),\gamma(s_0))=|\alpha'(s_0)|(s_1-s_0).$ Hence the LHS of the displayed inequality is actually $|d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))-|\alpha'(s_0)|(s_1-s_0)|$. As for the RHS, notice that the function $t\mapsto d(\gamma(t),\alpha(t))$ depends continuously on $t$ and is zero at $t=s_0$. Hence there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that for $|s_1-s_0|<\delta$ we have $d(\gamma(s_1),\alpha(s_1))<\epsilon/2$. Now for general $t\in [s_0,s_1]$ we have the triangle inequality
$$
|d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))-|\alpha'(t)|(s_1-s_0)|\leq |d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))-|\alpha'(s_0)|(s_0-s_1)|+(s_0-s_1)||\alpha'(t)|-|\alpha'(s_0)||.
$$
We may choose $\delta_2>0$ such that for $|s_1-s_0|<\delta_2$ we have $(s_0-s_1)||\alpha'(t)|-|\alpha'(s_0)||<\epsilon/2$. Then take $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$ we get the desired result from the inequality above. Q.E.D.
More updates: I think I obtained similar results as Pengin did below using (*):
Take $\delta$ such that (*) holds, then we have the direct inequality
\begin{align*}
\int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|dt&=\frac{1}{s_1-s_0}\int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|(s_1-s_0)dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{s_1-s_0}\int_{s_0}^{s_1}[d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))+\epsilon]dt=d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))+\epsilon.
\end{align*}
So we get the following result:
(**) For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|s_1-s_0|<\delta$ implies
$$
d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))\geq \int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|dt-\epsilon.
$$
By compactness $\epsilon$ may be chosen to not depend on $s_0$.
But given (**), how do we prove $|\alpha|\geq L(\alpha)$? The naive idea is to take the partition of $[0,1]$, say $0=s_0<s_1<\cdots<s_{n-1}<s_n=1$ and consider
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d(\alpha(s_{k}),\alpha(s_{k+1}))
$$
which is $\leq |\alpha|$ by definition. By the inequality above we get
$$
|\alpha|\geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d(\alpha(s_{k}),\alpha(s_{k+1}))\geq \int_{0}^1 |\alpha'(t)|dt-(n-1)\epsilon.
$$
But the problem is $(n-1)\epsilon$ depends on $n$. If we can show that $|\alpha|\geq L(\alpha)-\epsilon$ we would be done. So somehow what I have obtained is not strong enough.

First, we restrict ourselves to a neighborhood in which $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism. Then let's define $\rho:[0, \delta)\to T_{\alpha(s_0)} M $ such that $\alpha(s_0 + t) = \exp_{\alpha(s_0)} (\rho(t))$. Notice that $\rho$ is smooth, $\rho(0)=0$ and that $d(\alpha(s_0+t), \alpha(s_0)) = |\rho(t)|$. Also observe that $\alpha'(s_0) = d\exp_{\alpha(s_0)}(0) \circ \rho'(0) = \rho'(0)$, where we identify $T_{0} T_{\alpha(s_0)}M = T_{\alpha(s_0)}M$ and use $d \exp_{\alpha(s_0)}(0) = \text{id}$. Using that
$$|\rho(t)|=|t\rho'(0)+o(t)| = t |\alpha'(0)| + o(t)$$
as $t\to 0$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
d(\alpha(s_0+t),\alpha(s_0)) = t |\alpha'(0)| + o(t) \geq \int_{s_0}^{s_0+t} |\alpha'(s)|ds + o(t) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
as $t\to 0$, where in the last step $o(t)$ may be chosen to not be dependent on $s_0$ by smoothness of everything. Although this is not exactly the inequality you wanted, it's good enough to show the bound $|\alpha|\geq L(\alpha)$.
Edit: Take $\epsilon >0$ and choose $t_0$ sufficiently small such that the error term $o(t)$ from $(1)$ satisfies $o(t)>-\epsilon t$ for $t<t_0$. Then we partition the interval $[0,1]$ into finitely many intervals of lengths less than $t_0$, $0=s_0 < s_1 < \ldots < s_n = 1$, to obtain by summation over $(1)$ that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} d(\alpha(s_{k+1}), \alpha (s_k)) \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{s_k}^{s_{k+1}} |\alpha'(t)|dt  - \epsilon (s_{k+1} -s_k) = \int_0^1 |\alpha'(t)| dt - \epsilon.$$
Taking the supremum over all partitions gives $|\alpha| \geq \int_0^1 |\alpha'(t)|dt -\epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ gives the result.

Thank you for your reply! I obtained the same result (For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|s_1-s_0|<\delta$ implies $d(\alpha(s_1),\alpha(s_0))\geq \int_{s_0}^{s_1}|\alpha'(t)|dt-\epsilon$). But how does this imply $|\alpha|\geq L(\alpha)+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$? The worry I have is when you add up segments and get $\sum_{i=0}^n d(\alpha(s_i),\alpha(s_{i+1}))$ on the left hand side of the inequality, the right hand side will become $\int_0^1 |\alpha'(t)|dt+n\epsilon$ (assuming $s_0=0,s_n=1$). And it is not clear that $n\epsilon$ is going to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

I made some more edits according to this answer in my post. Would you be willing to explain more about how your argument follows? Thank you so much!

I edited my answer to clarify the last part. The point is that we need the error term to be of higher order than the partition length, in my case meaning $o(t)/t \to 0$ as $t\to 0$. Your inequality cannot work because you would need to show that $\epsilon / \delta = n\epsilon \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$, otherwise you cannot guarantee that after summation, the error remains small, as you said. @TianyiWang

Ok I understand now. Thank you so much!
